# Using pseudo element to create custom line through not working when text is wrapped

Tags: html, css, layout, styles, responsive

As above, I want to make custom line through that response to the wrapped text
not via line through. Is it possible to make it happens?

Comment: my codepen: https://codepen.io/joelamltc/pen/odqBwX

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Update your css and html like this
css

```
    .text1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      width: 600px;
      background: yellow;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      color:#f10;
      text-decoration:line-through;

    }
    .text1 p{ color:#000; }
HTML

    <div class="text1"><p>Hellow World!Hellow World!Hellow World!Hellow World!</p></div>
```

Comment: not via line-through, i need to control the line like animation. but thx